# Pass GeoJSON to php and html

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, leaflet, geojson

I have a leaflet map via which users can draw a polygon, then the goal is to display the bounding box they selected, and send this information via email (or other action), all on the same page.

I have the leaflet no problem, and a popup which displays the coordinates, however passing the coordinates into php is proving troublesome.

Is there an order in which the javascript and php code must be placed?
Would it just be easier to put the mailing functionality on another page?

Edit to include full code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php 

use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer;
use PHPMailer\PHPMailer\Exception;
require 'C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-includes\PHPMailer\Exception.php';
require 'C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-includes\PHPMailer\PHPMailer.php';
require 'C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\wp-includes\PHPMailer\SMTP.php';

$product="test product"; //input variable

if (isset($_POST["submit"])) {
$mail = new PHPMailer();

// SMTP server settings
$mail->isSMTP();
$mail->Host = 'x';
$mail->SMTPAuth = true;
$mail->Username = 'x';
$mail->Password = 'x';
$mail->SMTPSecure = 'tls';
$mail->Port = 587;

// Mail header settings
$mail->setFrom('x', 'x');
$mail->addReplyTo('x', 'x');
$mail->WordWrap=50;
$mail->IsHTML(true);
$mail->addAddress('x', 'test client'); // replace with variable: provider

$message    .= "<p><b>Submitted by:</b> " . $_POST["lename"] . "</p>";
$message    .= "<p><b>Email:</b> " . $_POST["email"] . "</p>";
$message    .= "<p><b>Comments:</b> " . $_POST["comments"] . "</p>";
$message    .= "<p><b>Product:</b> " . $product .  "</p>";
$message    .= "<p><b>Bounding box:</b> " . $boundingString . "</p>"; // bb from map

$mail->Body    = $message;
$mail->AltBody = $_POST["name"] . " " . $_POST["email"] . " " . $_POST["comments"];

if (!$mail->Send()) {
    $error_message = "Message could not be sent.<br><br>";
    $error_message .= "Mailer Error: " . $mail->ErrorInfo;
    exit;
    }
else {
    $success_message = "Test successful";
    }
}
?>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    
    <title>Piksel Visor development facility - Leaflet</title>
    
    <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="docs/images/favicon.ico" />

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.css" integrity="sha512-hoalWLoI8r4UszCkZ5kL8vayOGVae1oxXe/2A4AO6J9+580uKHDO3JdHb7NzwwzK5xr/Fs0W40kiNHxM9vyTtQ==" crossorigin=""/> <!--leaflet map css-->
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/leaflet@1.8.0/dist/leaflet.js" integrity="sha512-BB3hKbKWOc9Ez/TAwyWxNXeoV9c1v6FIeYiBieIWkpLjauysF18NzgR1MBNBXf8/KABdlkX68nAhlwcDFLGPCQ==" crossorigin=""></script> <!--leaflet map script-->
    
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.4/leaflet.draw.css" /> <!--control panel css-->
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/leaflet.draw/1.0.4/leaflet.draw.js"></script> <!--control panel script-->
    
    <script src="https://smtpjs.com/v3/smtp.js"></script> <!--emailer script-->
    
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script> <!--JQuery-->

    <style>
        html, body {
            height: 100%;
            margin: 0;
        }
        .leaflet-container {
            height: 400px;
            width: 600px;
            max-width: 100%;
            max-height: 100%;
        }
        .center {
            text-align: center;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
<img src="http://piksel-market.cimne.com:8000/wp-content/uploads/2022/06/LOGO_Preview-File_Transparent-1-1024x570.png" class="center" style="width: 200px;">
<p>
<div id="map" style="width: 80%; height: 60%; margin: auto;"></div>
<script>

    var map = L.map('map', {drawControl: false}).setView([41.387, 2.168], 7);

    var tiles = L.tileLayer('https://{s}.tile.openstreetmap.org/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
        maxZoom: 19,
        attribution: '&copy; <a href="http://www.openstreetmap.org/copyright">OSM</a>'
    }).addTo(map);

    // FeatureGroup is to store editable layers
    var drawnItems = new L.FeatureGroup();
    map.addLayer(drawnItems);
    var drawControl = new L.Control.Draw({
        draw: {
            polyline: false, // options for controls
            circlemarker: false,
            circle: false,
            marker: false
            },
        edit: {
            featureGroup: drawnItems, poly:  {allowIntersection: false}
        }
    });
    map.addControl(drawControl);


    map.on(L.Draw.Event.CREATED, function (event) {
        var layer = event.layer;
        var latLngs;
        
        popupContent = layer.toGeoJSON ?
        JSON.stringify(layer.toGeoJSON()) : "(no data)";

        drawnItems.addLayer(layer);
        
        layer.bindPopup(popupContent).openPopup();
        // if (type === 'circle') {
        //  latLngs = layer.getLatLng();
        //}
        // else
        //latLngs = layer.getLatLngs(); // Returns an array of the points in the path.
    
        // save to db, email, whatever
        var popupContentPass = popupContent;

    });
    
    $.ajax({
        contentType: "application/json",
        method: 'POST',
        url: 'visor_test.php',
        data: {boundingPass: popupContent}, 
        success: function(data){
        console.log(data);
        }
        });

</script>
<p>
<body>

<?php
    $bounding=json_decode($_POST["boundingPass"]);
    $boundingString = json_encode($bounding);
    //echo $boundingString;
?>

<div id="visor-form" class=center style="width=20%; margin: auto;">
<form class="visor-form-group" method="post" action="<?php $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]; ?>">
<fieldset>
    <div class="fields-group">
        <label for="lename">Name</label>
        <input id="lename" name="lename" type="text" placeholder="Name" required>
    </div>

    <div class="fields-group">
        <label for="email">Email Address</label>
        <input id="email" name="email" type="email" placeholder="Email Address" required>
    </div>

    <div class="fields-group">
        <label for="comments">Comments</label>
        <textarea name="comments" id="comments" cols="30" rows="5" required></textarea>
    </div>
          
        <input type="hidden" id="boundingString">

    <div class="pure-controls">
        <button type="submit" class="button-group" name="submit">Submit</button>
    </div>
</fieldset>
</form>
</div>
</body>
</html>
</body>
</html>
```

Any further information needed let me know. Caveat: I'm not a php/javascript coder by any means.

What doesn't work:

1. The mail sends ok everything except the bounding coordinates.
2. The error : Notice: Undefined index: boundingPass in C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\visor\visor_test.php on line 151 appears
3. After sending, the following errors appear:

Notice: Undefined variable: message in C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\visor\visor_test.php on line 31
Notice: Undefined variable: boundingString in C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\visor\visor_test.php on line 35
Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp64\www\wordpress\visor\visor_test.php on line 38

I assume this is due to the order of the code and some will need to be relocated?

Comment: What **exactly** is not working with the current code? Is this a PHP problem, a JS problem, or an AJAX problem? And why did you share so much mailing code if this is a problem with GeoJSON?

Comment: It's difficult to debug without the full code. I have some observations - maybe you can explain: the mailer uses variable `$bounding`; the variable `$bounding` is set (after the mailer sent the message?) from a post variable `"boundingPass"`;there seems to be no field named `"boundingPass"` in the form; there's an ajax call to a `visor_test.php` with a `"boundingBox"` field (what does that do?)

Comment: Edited to include the full page and error descriptions. Sorry for the confusion and thanks for your time.

Comment: Does `visor_test.php` do anything relevant?

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Warnings about undefined variables should not be too hard to resolve

Comment: There seem to be a lot of issues there. Php errors might be generated by the ajax call to `visor_test.php`, which is appears not to be relevant. You should somehow send "boundingString" data to the mailer. I suggest you see what happens if you make these changes: 1) At the end of `map.on(...` function add `document.getElementById('boundingString') = popupContent;`. 2) add the name to the hidden input: `<input type="hidden" id="boundingString" name="boundingString">` 3) comment out the ajax call